# setBackgroundresource en un ImageButton

Tags: java, android

Quiero añadir un efecto "gif" a un imageButton

```
tiraDado.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dado);
    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) tiraDado.getBackground();
    frameAnimation.start();
```

tiraDado es un ImageButton

El problema es que la imagen estática se queda delante del efecto gif

```
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/iconodado" android:duration="1000"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/iconodado2" android:duration="1000"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/iconodado3" android:duration="1000"/>
```

Comment: Orz no se entiende lo que te pasa. Puedes ser un poco mas explicito?

Comment: Verás, trato de crear el efecto gif que se le aplica a una ImageView a través de un dado.xml con las imágenes que van a ir rotando, el problema es que lo quiero hacer en un ImageButton

Comment: te refieres a que dado es un gif? dado.gif?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu imagen es un .gif no podrás cargarlo simplemente con definir como fondo el .gif en realidad los gif en `ImageButton` no son soportados.

Como opción separa en frames tu imagen y agrega las imagenes dentro del folder `/drawable`, por ejemplo `animation.xml`:

```
<animation-list android:oneshot="false" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame1" android:duration="2" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame2" android:duration="2" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame3" android:duration="2" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame4" android:duration="2" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame5" android:duration="2" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame6" android:duration="2" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame7" android:duration="2" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame8" android:duration="2" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame9" android:duration="2" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame10" android:duration="2" />
</animation-list>
```

y de esta forma carga la animación a tu `ImageButton`:

```
  <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        ...
        ...
        android:src="@drawable/animation"/>
```

Comment: Si justo eso es lo que tengo, el problema es que el ImageButton sigue estático

Comment: La respuesta es valida para ImageView, con ImageButton el efecto "gif" se queda dando vueltas en el fondo con la imagen estática delante